# What do you receive from the community? What does the community gives to Ethereum?

Tags: dao, explorers

I am happy to be here. My name is Irina. I am researching how community helps to stakeholder- Ethereum, what advantages or help (or any other things) the community gives to members?
I would be grateful for your opinion and comments. And if you have 15 minutes to discuss it on an interview.

Comment: This type of question are better for social networks like twitter, reddit, discord, etc.